# How do I time stamp a logfile with Rake?

Tags: ruby, datetime, rake

What is a simple, clear and concise way to continually timestamp a logfile in a Rake task?

I see there is a [`#timestamp`](https://ruby.github.io/rake/Rake/FileCreationTask.html#method-i-timestamp) method; however, after reading its description, I'm still not sure how to use it:

```
timestamp()

Time stamp for file creation task.
This time stamp is earlier than any other time stamp.
```

Also, am I effectively using the `file` and `directory` methods? Is there a better way?

```
require 'time'

task :default => [:timestamp]

directory 'some/path/to'
file 'some/path/to/some.log' => ['some/path/to']
task :timestamp => ['some/path/to/some.log'] do
  File.open('some/path/to/some.log', 'a') do |f|
    f.puts Time.now.iso8601
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
$ cat some/path/to/some.log
2017-04-10T14:16:44-07:00
2017-04-10T14:16:55-07:00
$ rake
$ cat some/path/to/some.log
2017-04-10T14:16:44-07:00
2017-04-10T14:16:55-07:00
2017-04-10T14:21:14-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

this timestamp is not what you need. Rake does not support what you want. You can pipe the standard output to "ts" tool from "moreutils" packages available in Debian to add timestamps.

This method is used for working with file timestamps.